# only secure content is displayed after adding google font api

Tags: c#, html, css, google-font-api

We are developing a Web App with `MVC4` and `Jquery Mobile`. All works well but we decided to use Google font instead of normal font.

It works well in development in IE browser but when we deployed in Production in **public url** then users are getting **"only secure content is displayed"** only in IE browser. Please guide me. Below is my code.

```
<head>
    <title>@ViewBag.Title - Highway905 Mobile App</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link href="~/favicon.ico" rel="shortcut icon" type="image/x-icon" />
    <link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Oswald' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
    <link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto+Condensed' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
    <link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
</head>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This happens because the CDN links for the fonts are not secure, when the browser is expecting them to be. Just change the "http" to "https" so that it looks like this:

```
<link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Oswald' rel='stylesheet'    type='text/css'>
<link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto+Condensed' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
<link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
```

Edit:
While you're at it, you should make just one request for the fonts, by putting all the requests into one URL.

```
<link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto|Roboto+Condensed|Oswald' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
```

Comment: Is there anything you can do about this if the links cannot be HTTPS? I've got 3 HTTP links on my site to my own trusted domains, they're just not HTTPS.

Answer (score 0):

You could also just link an empty stylesheet

```
<link href="/Content/empty.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
```

with only single line inside the css file

```
@import url("//fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Oswal");
```

@import statement must be the first row in your css. No comments or any other style settings above it.

As import url does not specify if http or https should be used,  extrenal css will be loaded over http when http is used or over https when https is used